# Tor proxy as webservice

Tags: tor

I would like to create a page, where users could type website address, and as a result I'd show the webpage result with clickable links etc.

But request/response should go through TOR. Is there any package for that?

Answer (score 0):

Tor default proxy port is 8118. you have to first download privoxy [here](http://www.privoxy.org/)

To chain Privoxy and Tor, both running on the same system, you would use something like:

```
          forward-socks5   /               127.0.0.1:9050 .
```

change its config to work with tor by uncommenting the above line

c# does not use sock proxies so that we have to run Tor and Provoxy at same. now you can send every web request using tor.

Code:-

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://whatismyipaddress.com/");
        request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8118");
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")))
            {
                string contenu = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(regex.Match(contenu).Groups[0].Value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I meant a service on the remote machine. For example, I go to the http://mysuperproxy where I type in URL I want to see, and that service returns the URL content via TOR installed on that remote machine